# Inserting new row instead of Updating

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to update a profile in the database without passing the profile id as a paramater and instead of updating I am adding new row. I tried to use the **getLastInsertId()** but it did not work.

```
public function editProfile(){

    if (isset($this->data)){

        $Client = $this->Client->find('first', array(
        'fields' => array('email','username','first_name','surname','country','phone_prefix','phone'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Client.email' => $this->request->query['email'],
            'Client.client_type' => $this->request->query['client_type']
             ),
        )
    );


 if($this->request->is('get')) {

        if($data = $this->Client->save($this->request->query,array('first_name','surname','country','phone_prefix','phone')))
        {
            $this->Client->id = $this->Client->getLastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to update a record in your Client model based on the email and client type because *(I assume)* you don't know the id.

Try changing your code to get the id based on the information you have-

```
public function editProfile(){

if($this->request->is('get')) {
  if (isset($this->data)){

    $conditions = array('conditions' => array(
            'email' => $this->request->query['email'],
            'client_type' => $this->request->query['client_type']
         ));
    $this->Client->id = $this->Client->field('id', $conditions);

    if($this->Client->save($this->request->query,array('id', 'first_name','surname','country','phone_prefix','phone')))
    {
      $this->setFlash('success');
    }else{
      $this->setFlash('fail');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it seems you have two possible keys:

1. The client email
2. The last saved id

First, using the last saved id seems very fragile - how can you be sure this will always be the record you want to update? Best to avoid this approach.

However, if you have the user's email you can use the following method:

```
$client = $this->Client->findByEmail($this->request->data['Client']['email']);
$id = $client['Client']['id'];
```

You now have the client record id available to use in your save. Something like:

```
$data = array();
$data['Client']['id'] = $id;
$data['Client']['fieldFromForm'] = $this->data['Client']['fieldFromForm'];

$this->Client->save($data);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Without the id, cake  will assume that you are adding a new Client. To update via save you'll need to tell it which Client.id to update in some way. Is there some reason that you can't provide the Client.id? The usual approach is to have Client.id present in a hidden input on your edit view which you can then pass to the edit action...

Comment: I added this line and it worked. $this->request->query['id'] = $Client['Client']['id.'] Thanks for you reply